# Where does Java System.getProperty retrieve user.home?

Tags: java

Found similar samples but none answered the question from where the user.home value is retrieved when not explicitly set.

Per researching :

System.**getenv** - retrieves environment variables set on the OS.

System.**getProperty** - retrieves variables set wtihin the JVM via the -D option.

Working with user.home and changed this value via the Windows RegEdit to c:\MyFolder\User1\TempDir

```
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders
```

The following test executes both getenv and getProperty.

```
public class SystemPropertyTest 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)  
    {
        System.out.println("user.home = " + System.getenv("user.home"));
        System.out.println("user.home = " + System.getProperty("user.home"));
        
    }
}
```

getenv returns :  c:\MyFolder\User1\TempDir

Even running "set user.home" at the command prompt returns : c:\MyFolder\User1\TempDir

getProperty returns : c:\Users\User1

Since I never set the user.home within the Java runtime, from where is the user.home being retrieve for the getProperty call and can it be manipulated at the OS level without making a setProperty call or passing in a value via -D?

Comment: `user.name` or `user.home`? You’ve mentioned both.

Comment: Thanks. Corrected the original post to be user.home which is the focus.

Comment: Given modifying the `USERPROFILE` environment variable doesn't affect the Java process, I assume it uses some Windows API that reports your actual user profile directory.

Comment: Have you read the documentation? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties--

Comment: Presumably, based on [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/964363/how-do-i-change-the-user-profile-location-in-windows-10), it uses the `ProfilesDirectory` in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList` registry key, but I have no interest in mucking with that to verify that (and nor should you, because it can break your Windows profile AFAIK!), and I haven't got the Java code checked out to search for it.

Comment: @aled There is nothing in your link that answers the question.

Comment: You may want to explain why you want to change your `user.home`, because `c:\Users\User1` **is** your home directory, maybe instead you just need to worry about `user.dir` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current implementation as of JDK 21 ([source code](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/890adb6410dab4606a4f26a942aed02fb2f55387/src/java.base/windows/native/libjava/java_props_md.c#L228)) is to search the registry [known key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/knownfolderid) `FOLDERID_Profile`:

```
hr = SHGetKnownFolderPath(&FOLDERID_Profile, KF_FLAG_DONT_VERIFY, NULL, &u_path);
```

This should provide the same result that the environment variable `%USERPROFILE%`.